# c++ int switch statement always goes to `default`

Tags: c++, int, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that is based off an int comparison, but for some reason, it keeps failing on true comparisons, and skipping to the default. Here's my code:

```
string Error(int errorNum, int send=1, int crash=1)
{
  string errorType;
  switch(errorNum)
  {
    case 10:
      errorType = "Port number";
    ...
    default:
      errorType = "Unknown";
  }
...
}
```

I keep calling it with the argument of `10`, but when I do, it fails. The equivelant `if... else if... else` method works, and here it is as well:

```
string Error(int errorNum, int send=1, int crash=1)
{
  string errorType;
  if (errorNum == 10)                 // Normally I'd use braces,
    errorType = "Port number";        // but here, it just clutters
  ...
  else
    errorType = "Unknown";
  ...
}
```

Comment: You've not missed adding your `break`s, have you?

Comment: Do you have a `break` before `default`? If not then it will look like it is hitting `default` because it will fall through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely missing a `break` in the case. Make sure that at the end of each `case`  you include `break` or it will fall through to the next one.

```
string Error(int errorNum, int send=1, int crash=1)
{
  string errorType;
  switch(errorNum)
  {
    case 10:
      errorType = "Port number";
      break; // If this is not here it will fall throughto the next case or default

    default:
      errorType = "Unknown";
  }
  return errorType;
}
```

Comment: Okay, 4 answers in 60 seconds. Wow.

Comment: Common problems usually get quite a few really quick responses.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use `break` then the all the subsequent case statements will be executed after the matching case.

So in your your case, it executes both the case parts and overwrites the value `errorType` which gives you the impression that it directly jumps to default case.

---

**To add an interesting update...**

Note that having braces around case statements would make no difference. In fact, the following code is valid C++ and would work as expected:

```
switch(var)
{

  {
   case 1:
     cout<<"case 1"<<endl;
  }
     cout<<"This is also part of case 1"<<endl;

   case 2:
  {
     cout<<"case 2 "<<endl;
  }

}
```

Note the braces are NOT misplaced.

Here the *outside* `cout` is also a part of the `case 1`.  After evaluating the control expression `var`, control will jump straight to the matching case. The braces around `case 1` merely introduces a new scope and has no bearing over what a *case* really constitutes. So right way is to put `break` statements if you don't want to fall-through the rest of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a break before default? If not then it will look like it is hitting default because it will fall through.

Answer (score 1):

Each case statement will need a break clause, otherwise it will fall through to the next statement.

e.g.

```
   case 10: 
        errorType = "Port number";
        break;
    default: 
        errorType= "Unknown";
        break;
```

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0t5wee3(v=vs.80).aspx for more detail

Depending on your situation, it may even be better to return the string from within the switch. The return statement will not fall through

```
case 10: 
     return "Port number";
default: 
     return "Unknown";
```